Amazon s3 folder structure and crawler setup to create table with partitions
I have s3 folder which is created manauly using Python shell script
My s3 folder looks like this
s3://my_bucket/landing_zone/year=2024/month=10/day=01/sales/file.csv
s3://my_bucket/landing_zone/year=2024/month=10/day=01/account/file.csv

I given two tables as example i have many tables under each date (consider 10 tables for each date)
I need to setup one crawler to scan all tables
Currently I tried to create crawler With this path
s3://my_bucket/landing_zone/

It created tables sales, account but partitions are not recognized.
In my catalog I expect table name as last folder name like sales, account and other key value pairs as partitions (year,month, date)
I can't change folder structure, but if no solutions give me the folder I should follow.
Is this achievable, how?
Thanks for solutions.

can you try putting the table name at the start instead. So for example: s3://my-bucket/landing_zone/sales/year=2024/month=10/day=01/file.csv.
Refer to this to see how a crawler determines when to create partitions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html#crawler-s3-folder-table-partition

The above structure will work, but as I said we have n number of tables is it ok to create like this folder.

Well, AWS glue quotas say that it supports 1,000,000 tables per account and 200,000 per database, both can be adjustable. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/glue.html#limits_glue

In the above structure also it is expecting for each path one crawler to have intended table names with proper partition, if i set one crawler to path up to landing_zone  it is considering sales and account as partition_0 and table name as landing_zone.

can you show me how the crawler is set up? Specially the target path? is it s3://my-bucket/landing_zone/?

s3://my_bucket/landing_zone/sales/year=2022/month=06/date=08/file.csv
s3://my_bucket/landing_zone/sales/year=2022/month=06/date=09/file.csv
s3://my_bucket/landing_zone/account/year=2022/month=06/date=09/file.csv

so in the above s3 folders (file name is different not unique )
if set crawler to this path    s3://my_bucket/landing_zone/   table name is taking as landing_zone and  it considering table name also as partition (sales as partitin_0)
if i set path upto table name   s3://my_bucket/landing_zone/sales/ like this then it is working as intended

s3://my_bucket/landing_zone/sales/
s3://my_bucket/landing_zone/account/
I am adding each(multiple) data source in one crawler (its working but still is this correct way)
